# Difficulty in solving a question regarding the sum of two arithmetic sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

Hey guys, I am having a problem solving a question regarding the sum of two linear sequeneces. Using the equation $S_n=\frac{n}{2}[2a(n-1)d] = 15=5n$, whenever I do try to solve it, I get $25-5n=\frac{30-10n}{n}$. Further simplifying this into a quadratic equation, I get $n=1\space and \space n=6$. However, this is misleading and instead, leaves me even more confused. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be adding the expression for the general terms of each sequence, not the sums of each.

$T_{A, n} = 7 + (n-1)(-2) = 9-2n$

$T_{B, n} = 3 + (n-1)(-3) = 6-3n$

$\therefore T_{A+B, n} = 9-2n+6-3n \\= 15-5n$

Answer (score 2):

$$T_1=[7+(n-1)(-2)]=(9-2n)$$
$$T_2=[3+(n-1)(-3)]=[6-3n]$$
Hence $$T_1+T_2=[15-5n]$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood the question. It just wants you to add together two terms: the $n$th term of A plus the $n$th term of B. You do not need to work out the sum of either sequence.

Comment: Thank you, I did misunderstand the question.